# Smoke Won’t Stop Emitting When “Use Flow” Is Unchecked

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I don’t know what information to give. I set a key frame with “Use Flow” checked, then I add a key frame on the next frame, with “Use Flow” unchecked.

The properties tab show that it is unchecked, and does so at the correct frame, but smoke continues to emit forever.

I’ve tried putting key frames in different places, doing a key frame at the start and the end of my animation, shrinking the emitter, and resolutions from 32 to 512. I have also tried baking manually vs using the playback. I’m not sure what else to try.

I’ve read dozens of Reddit and other forum posts, all of which say to do exactly what I did (keyframing “Use Flow”).

I’m using Blender 4.0.2

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but since you already said you've done exactly what you are supposed to do (and I cannot immediately see a flaw in your description), just a simple guess: do you mean it emits all the time or the smoke is just not disappeared after the keyframe to uncheck? I don't think that's your issue, I just do not see anything wrong. Maybe you could upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the intructions there to edit it into question? Only the basic setup which does not work is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I mean that it emits the whole time. I would like the smoke that has already emitted to stay floating around, but stop any further smoke from generating. I will try to upload the file, thank you for the suggestion. It’s a basic, fairly empty scene, with two objects to collide with. I have tested it without these objects as well though

Answer (score 0):

The smoke stops emitting immediately when the keyframe unchecks *Use Flow*. I've removed the collision object etc. and gave the emitter object some movement on the X axis so that it starts moving before the emission stops, you can see on frame 60 it still emits smoke, on frame 61 there is no more smoke coming out of the sphere, and later on frame 70 the sphere is not even within the *Adaptive Domain* anymore indicating there is no smoke emitted:

[image: emitter with stopped inflow]

There are many things I would have changed in your setup. First of all, you have set the *Buoyancy Density* in your domain set to 0, which means the smoke does neither rise (buoyancy > 0) nor sink (buoyancy < 0), but the one for *Heat* is at its maximum with 5 which has more effect if the emitter would be set to *Fire + Smoke* instead of just *Smoke*.

Then the *Vorticity* is quite high with 0.3, also the _Strength of the *Noise*  with a value of 1.

The *Threshold* in the *Adaptive Domain* is quite low at 0.001 as well.

All this taken together results in the smoke just staying around the emitter for a very long time even after the emission has stopped. The main problems are the *Buoyancy Density*, the *Vorticity* and the *Noise*.

When I set the following values:

- *Gas* >

  - *Buoyancy Density*: 1.0
  - *Vorticity*: 0.1
  - *Noise* >

    - *Strength*: 0.5

it immediately becomes more obvious that the smoke stopped emitting at some point. However, this will make the smoke rise faster. If you do not want that, set the values back to what you had or something between that and my suggestions, but maybe then consider to enable the *Dissolve* option to have the smoke disappear over time or else you might not notice it stopped emitting.

Comment: Thank for this! The reason I went with the high heat and low buoyancy is that I found that higher buoyancy kept the smoke from spreading outwards, it would eventually start only going up. Heat fixed this (I’m curious why the limit is only 5). [I sent the comment on accident]. I also upped the vorticity because it made the smoke look more realistic in my opinion. In that particular scene, I don’t need to see the smoke disappearing, but all the smoke in the background is very taxing on my pc. My goal is to have the smoke continue to flow around, so I feel dissolve wouldn’t work for that

Comment: I will continue tweaking the parameters you suggested, just wanted to give my reasons. Thank you for taking the time to look at this! Edit: and I lowered the domain threshold to help with dissolve in a different design, but I forgot to change it back. One thing that confused me is why the smoke stays there at all, shouldn’t the high heat keep that from happening?

Comment: @Koast No, as I mention in my answer the high _Heat_ mainly affects smoke when you have set the emitter to _Fire + Smoke_, but you haven't, you're just emitting _Smoke_. The problem with the smoke staying around regarding your pc's performance is that the smoke is spreading out. The smoke contains more data and therefore resources, the more of the domain is filled with smoke, especially when using _Adaptive Domain_ this is apparent because the adaptive domain grows larger with the spreading smoke. Of course not using it makes it worse because then it always simulates the whole domain.